# Randomizing coordinates

Tags: python

I am quite new to Python, but I find it is really fun to code

```py
dictionary_of_locations = {

    'location_1': (2214, 1026), # x, y coordinates
    'location_2': (2379, 1016),
    'location_3': (2045, 1092),
    'location_4': (2163, 1080),
    'location_5': (2214, 1080),
    'location_6': (2262, 1078),

}
```

I want to run a code that selects the location coordinates and randomizes x and y values by +-15

what exactly I am trying to do is:

```py
for i in dictionary_of_locations.values():
    pyautogui.click(i), print('clicking on location ' + str(i + 1) + ' !'), time.sleep(.75)
```

Comment: Lookup the `random` module in Python.

Comment: To get a random integer in the range -15..+15 do `random.randint(-15,15)`. Tuples are immutable so your code needs to create a new randomized coordinate based on the old one, something like `newcoord = (oldcoord[0]+random.randint(-15,15),oldcoord[1]+random.randint(-15,15))`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `random.randint`:

```py
import random
loc = ... # Do whatever to get your desired coordinates

loc = (loc[0] + random.randint(-15, 15), loc[1] + random.randint(-15, 15))
```

Or if you don't want just integers but also floats:

```py
import random
loc = ... # Do whatever to get your desired coordinates

loc = (loc[0] + random.random() * 30 - 15, loc[1] + random.random() * 30 - 15)
```

Comment: Thomas Kimber's answer also has the good idea of encapsulating this into a reusable function.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I like about python is how it gently steers people into thinking functionally. So when I see a problem like this, I think - *"What single, reusable function would really help in this situation?"*

And in answer to that question, I guess some kind of *blurrer* that, given an input and some parameters, spits out a blurred version. Maybe we want to blurr by a fixed amount (+-15 as per your question) or maybe later, we might want to blur by some amount defined as a ratio.

Here's a starting point that covers the first idea (fixed range of blur), we'll call the input value **value** and the amount of blur, **blur** (other naming ideas are available).

Python has a lot of useful randomisation code in its [random](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) module, so we'll import that for some of that functionality too.

```
import random
def blur(value, blur):
    blur_sign = random.choice([-1,1]) # is the blur going to be positive or negative?
    blur_rand = random.randint(0,blur) * blur_sign # pick a random number up to "blur" and multiply by sign
    return value + blur_rand
```

> N.B. use of `random.choice` in the above is probably a bit on the
> clunky side, as others have demonstrated here, calling
> `random.randint` with a lower-bound, upper-bound as parameters is a
> cleaner way of getting the range you want and will cross the
> positive/negative without having to expressly setting it as I've done
> here.

Try it out, feed the 'blur' function with any value, and some blurring parameter, and it should spit out the kinds of results you want. Now you've got a function that does the job, just use some python to glue it into whatever workflow you're interested in.

An example of how that might look given your existing code:

```
for x,y in dictionary_of_locations.values():
    i = (blur(x,15), blur(y,15))
    pyautogui.click(i), print('clicking on location ' + str(i + 1) + ' !'), time.sleep(.75)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `randint(lb, ub)` to get a random integer in between the lower / upper bound

```
from random import randint
for loc in dictOfLoc:
    newLoc = (dictOfLoc[loc][0] + randint(-15, 15),
              dictOfLoc[loc][1] + randint(-15, 15))
    dictOfLoc[loc] = newLoc
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use [numpy.random.randomint()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randint.html)

Example:

```py
import numpy as np
import time

dictionary_of_locations = {

    'location_1': (2214, 1026), # x, y coordinates
    'location_2': (2379, 1016),
    'location_3': (2045, 1092),
    'location_4': (2163, 1080),
    'location_5': (2214, 1080),
    'location_6': (2262, 1078),

}

def get_random(x, y):
    """
    Get (x, y) and return (random_x, random_y) according to rand_range
    +1 is added to high bound because randint is high exclusive [low, high)
    :param x: position x
    :param y: position y
    :return: random values for x and y with range 15
    """
    rand_range = 15  # for -/+ 15

    x_low = x - rand_range
    x_high = x + rand_range + 1
    y_low = y - rand_range
    y_high = y + rand_range + 1
    rand_x = np.random.randint(low=x_low, high=x_high)
    rand_y = np.random.randint(low=y_low, high=y_high)

    return rand_x, rand_y

for location, positions in dictionary_of_locations.items():
    current_x, current_y = positions
    new_x, new_y = get_random(current_x, current_y)
    print(f'clicking on {location} (x, y): ({new_x},{new_y}) !')
    time.sleep(.75)

# output
# clicking on location_1 (x, y): (2209,1040) !
# clicking on location_2 (x, y): (2364,1005) !
# clicking on location_3 (x, y): (2052,1086) !
# clicking on location_4 (x, y): (2160,1092) !
# clicking on location_5 (x, y): (2222,1079) !
# clicking on location_6 (x, y): (2275,1082) !
```